# Cleanup file of phone numbers that are not properly formatted

Tags: regex, macos, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with nearly 10,000 phone numbers in it and many were not formatted properly, e.g. `123-456-7890` and although I've cleaned up most I still have one pattern I'm not sure how to handle.  I used `sed` to clean up most of it and don't mind using either `sed` or `awk`, although I use `sed` more often then `awk`, to get one of the last groups (2306 line) formatted properly

Example:  `123  4567890` (3 tab 7) needs to be `123-456-7890` (3 dash 3 dash 4).

I know I can find the pattern and replace the tab easily enough using:

```
sed "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]\t[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/s/\t/-/" infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

However if I could augment the instruction to parse the 7 numbers, that are grouped together, at the same time it would make it easier for me to clean up what's left after this round.  I've done a fair amount of searching although I couldn't get anything I found from the list when I typed in the subject to work before following through with posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extended regular expressions and capturing groups:

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]{3})\t([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})$/\1-\2-\3/' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it worked.  Would you mind explaining the `sed` instruction compared to mine. I need to be sure it did't act on any other patten that still needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: I ran `diff` on the files and it only touched the target pattern so there's no need to explain the instruction as I'll read up on extended regular expressions, as I should anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

basicaly something like this will work for a phone number alone.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)[^0-9]*/\1/g;s/\(...\)\(...\)\(....\)/\1-\2-\3/' YourFile
```

now, you certainly have your phone number associate with other info, so extraction and filtering is more specific

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
echo "123  4567890" | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"");print substr($0,1,3)"-"substr($0,4,3)"-"substr($0,7,3)}'
123-456-789
```

It just removes all non numbers, then print it out in groups of three.